# How to set active my database from sleep command

Tags: mysql, database

I'm currently using **MySQL Query browser** to view the database of my website. Then I encountered this error

```
error 1049 unknown database 'testajax'
```

I already dropped this database after using it to test an ajax function. Then my website did not work liked it used to before. Specifically, I cannot `INSERT` but I can fetch some of the data from my database. I'm a beginner in MySQL, I looked at the tools tab, **MySQL Administrator > Server Connections** and then I saw this: [(Please click to see the image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNHh8.png) I found that my database (**crb**). Is on **sleep** command. Is this the reason that's why I cannot use my database? If yes, **how can I set my database to active** to use it again?

Comment: No, that has absolutely nothing to do with it, and that display doesn't mean the *database* is sleeping, it means an individual connection to it is. Perfectly normal.

Comment: thank you. Do you have an idea what's the best solution here?